# ESOL teacher claims present perfect equals s-form

Tags: grammar, american-english, learning

A person I know learns English as a second language. The teacher introduced some basic grammar concepts, mostly simple present, past, and future. For some reason, he introduced present perfect as well. She showed me what he did on the whiteboard: he claims that present perfect is built using the `s-form of the verb` and not using `has/have + past participle`.

Does this mix-up make sense somehow?

**Edit:** I attached an image of the whiteboard. He explained that present perfect requires adding an "s" to the verb and is used when another person does something regular. For example:

> She eats cereals every morning.
>
> He walks the dog daily.

**Edit:** I removed the image again due to privacy concerns.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Without examples it's difficult to understand what you're asking

Comment: On the face of it, claiming that "present perfect is built using the s-form of the verb" sounds like nonsense. But it is nonsense to such a degree that it makes me wonder if perhaps it is not more likely that there was a miscommunication somewhere. Did your wife happen to take a picture of what was on the board, and if so, could you post it? Regardless of that, could your wife perhaps ask the teacher if she understood him or her correctly?

Comment: HE'S GONE to the shops.... SHE'S SEEN this movie three times... The CAR'S BROKEN DOWN, what do we do now?.... Did she understand that the shortened form of HE HAS =HE'S is the s-form??

Comment: Thank you both, @fev and linguisticturn. I added the image and a more specific example. Sorry for the slightly odd question here. It feels more like a rant.

Comment: @Mari-LouA she did, but I am talking about adding the s to the verb.

Comment: Oh dear, definitely wrong. The teacher's mixed up simple present in the 3rd person singular with "present prefect" That, or the teacher doesn't know what the PP is! Possibly, he's suffering from what is known as a "brain fart". It can happen to the best of us.

Comment: She mentioned it to him twice now, but he claims this is it, regardless of what any book says — it made me somewhat disbelieve what I learned. Hence I had to ask.

Comment: "Continous" on the board is spelled wrong too, it should be *continuous* Is the teacher very young, fresh out of college? If so, he's probably done an intensive CELTA course and shouldn't be teaching English.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147315/discussion-between-sebastian-dressler-and-mari-lou-a).

Comment: If a teacher [declares](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/610212/esol-teacher-claims-present-perfect-equals-s-form#comment1544441_610212) "regardless of what any book says" then suspect the teacher.

Comment: So, what's a good practice now with that question b/c there likely won't be a real answer and just comments?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a simple mistake on behalf of the teacher rather than a point of language.

Comment: @Greybeard Agreed. Leave closed.

Comment: The teacher has lost sight of the fact that _perfect_ here means "finished, completed," probably because its most common sense in modern English is "without flaw."  If the teacher knew this, the teacher would realize that it is ludicrous to use "present perfect" as the name of a verb form that applies to a habitual action.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a false premise.

Comment: Every other criticism on this page so far is accurate, and "simple present = information" and "present perfect = pattern, all the time, habit" are both false

Comment: Get a refund iff the teacher does not back down.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct. Based on the photo you provided, this teacher is hopelessly confused and presumably incompetent.

It's not even the only error on that board. "Verbs = actions" is clearly false, and phonetically spelling "eating" as "eedieen" (if I'm reading that right) is wrong in pretty much every dialect.

Comment: Pretty much every, but there are some language communities around New York City that use a pronunciation that could reasonably be described that way.

Comment: I thought the same thing about eedeen, but I can actually imagine some of my teenage students here in Toronto saying it. They could plausibly say it [like this](https://voca.ro/1iPcWZfcduvc).

Comment: The "d" is probably a (somewhat inaccurate) attempt to describe [flapping.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flapping) There are also dialects where word final "-ing" is just "-in." But the "ieen" puzzles me.

Comment: I think identifying verbs as 'doing words' as we used to in primary school is fine. I'm aware that it doesn't account for verbs like 'be' and that some linguists define verbs in terms of morphology or syntax (essentially saying a verb is something that behaves like a verb), but I don't think going down that rabbit hole would help your average language learner and it's certainly not grounds to judge someone incompetent. Overall I agree that's an unhappy board. I'm not sure that the crude pronunciation respellings are such a good idea fiuchr strikes me as more a hindrance than a help

Comment: and there are spelling errors. But in and of itself I don't think using the wrong name for something necessarily means you can't teach someone to speak the language well. I agree there does come a point where you have to say if he doesn't know that, what else doesn't he know? But present perfect is just a heading in a language textbook you don't need to know what it is to speak English. And anyway it's traditional grammatical terminology which isn't always grounded in rigorous linguistics. In Sanskrit the 'perfect' is called 'perfect' by Europeans solely because it looks like the Greek perfect

Comment: @Au101 Yes, the terms matter. If you look at the board, it's also wrong about what the simple present & present perfect are used for. Beyond that, it will leave learners confused when they inevitably read other resources, learn from other teachers, try to explain things to fellow learners, etc.

Comment: I think the terms matter a bit. I agree that it reflects poorly on the teacher in the same way turning up to a job as a tailor in clothes that don't fit does. I especially agree that it will confuse you if you use other resources or speak to other learners. But the teacher might well be very good at getting people to speak English, if not quite so good at getting them to identify tense-aspect-mood or parts of speech. Which much as it pains me to say it cause I did my degree in linguistics and when I teach languages I go down linguistic rabbit holes, may not be the most important thing

Comment: @Au101 That confusion is a serious problem! Regardless, the board is also wrong about how these verb forms are used.

Comment: @Au101 The verb-action equation unnecessary and stores up serious problems for the future, for example when learning the passive, or constructing complex noun phrases. If it's wrong and it doesn't benefit anybody, why do it? [Professional language teacher speaking]

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. (Linguistics BA speaking) Honestly I personally am a bit of a linguistics pedant and I don't fundamentally disagree with this answer at all. But as a very theory-minded person and teacher I have to be aware that many people are much more practically minded and I have to control my urge to turn a half hour language lesson into a 2-hour linguistics lecture with a break in the middle. And I thought this answer was a bit quick to judge and that a small contrary perspective could be justified.

Comment: As a linguist I care about tense-aspect-mood very much. But I know nobody in my French class cared that the imperfect isn't really a 'tense'. The 'tense is past, the aspect is imperfective. But we just called it a tense and you can justify that as well.

Comment: In answer to your question I certainly think that even if that equation may be unfashionable and outmoded it is hardly grounds to rule somebody's teaching incompetent. I think as a language learner it's perfectly adequate to distinguish nouns as the name you give something, whether concrete (book) or abstract (suffering), from something that you do, whether a more concrete action (write) or a more abstract thing that you do (suffer) or a thing that happens (rain vs rains). As a linguist it's useful because ultimately even a technical distinction is likely to have recourse to traditional terms

Comment: Paul Kroeger *Analyzing Grammar: An Introduction* (2005) "If there is a class whose prototypical members include most of the basic terms for volitional actions, e.g. *run, dance, eat, cut,* etc., we would give that class the label VERB."

Comment: @Au101 Did your fellow teachers tell you that you form the present perfect by adding S to the verb? And give you examples like "walks, drinks, sleeps" etc? No, of course not. Why? Because it's absolute nonsense. And it's the very, very opposite of practical. It's perfectly possible to teach English without any meta language at all. That doesn't mean it's ok to teach people baloney! What's going to happen when the student go on the internet to practise stuff or, heaven forfend, look at a book? [What the teacher should have done, and could have done]

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Without the rest of the lesson and with only that part of it that his been preserved for us on the whiteboard (which you would hope would be just notes) I think what we probably have is a mistake of terminology and nomenclature and not necessarily a mistake in language teaching. Whether that's important to the customer is up to them really. I agree that it will make things confusing if they look at other resources, but using non-standard or flat wrong terminology doesn't necessarily mean you can't teach correct usage

Comment: As I say, if I was teaching somebody to drive, I'd probably spend the first lesson explaining how the clutch works! But I know that most people don't want or need to know how a car works to make it go. I suspect what our poor teacher was trying to do was distinguish between habitual aspect and indicative/realis mood? I agree they've made a bit of a hash of it, but it's not something I'd worry about too much in an introductory English lesson

Comment: @Au101 I originally thought he'd just messed up his notes and just used the present perfect title for 3rd person. But the descriptions are wrong, and there's no excuse for giving different meanings for the  third person of the present tense! And the description further up  of the present tense is incomprehensible: "information" ??? It's all over the place. But the main thing I really dislike is the abysmal habit of trying to present every past present and future construction at the same time. There's zero point. And then there's the "the books are all wrong" reply to the students.

Comment: @Au101 They didn't do their homework.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147357/discussion-between-au101-and-araucaria-not-here-any-more).

Answer (score 7):

The teacher's claim is nonsense. Here is a basic explanation of the present perfect form from the [Learn English part of British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/present-perfect):

> The present perfect is formed from the present tense of the verb ***have***
> and the past participle of a verb.
>
> We use the present perfect:
>
> - for something that started in the past and continues in the present:
>
> > They'**ve been** married for nearly fifty years.
> >
> > She **has lived** in Liverpool all her life.
>
> - when we are talking about our experience up to the present:
>
> > I'**ve seen** that film before.
> >
> > I'**ve played** the guitar ever since I was a teenager.
> >
> > He **has written** three books and he is working on another one.

You can compare the examples above to the teacher's suggestion to create nonsense sentences:

> (x) They **marries** for nearly 50 years

It's also evident from the above example that merely putting an [s] would mix up subject-verb agreement.

Comment: May I asked why this is CW?

Comment: @Heartspring Unoriginality,. I was summarizing what was already obvious from other comments but deserved to be preserved as an answer.